# Cut some word from php available?

Tags: php, substring

Cut some word from php available ?

First access to page for example

```
www.mysite.com/test.php?ABD_07,_oU_876.00/8999&message=success
```

From my php code, i will get `$curreny_link_redirect` = `test.php?ABD_07,_oU_876.00/8999&message=success`

And i want to get `$curreny_link_redirect_new` = `test.php?ABD_07,_oU_876.00/8999`

( Cut `&message=success` )

How can i do ?

```
<?PHP
    $current_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $curreny_link_redirect = substr($current_link,1);
    $curreny_link_redirect_new = str_replace('', '&message=success', $curreny_link_redirect);
    echo $curreny_link_redirect_new;
?>
```

Comment: are you sure with $current_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?
it must be $current_link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Comment: @zerokavn well that should be correct too actually.

Comment: Why don't you just work with the `$_GET` array instead of `REQUEST_URI`?

Comment: echo `$_GET['message']`?

Comment: not str_replace('', '&message=success', $curreny_link_redirect); should be str_replace('&message=success', '', $curreny_link_redirect);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str_replace` call is inverse of what it should be. What you want to replace should be the first parameter, not the second.

```
//Wrong
$curreny_link_redirect_new = str_replace('', '&message=success', $curreny_link_redirect);

//Right
$curreny_link_redirect_new = str_replace('&message=success','', $curreny_link_redirect);
```

Answer (score 1):

While simple way to do this is to use regex (or even static with `str_replace()`), I recommend to use built-in functions for url handling. This may be useful when working with complex parameters or multiple parameters:

```
$data = 'www.mysite.com/test.php?ABD_07,_oU_876.00/8999&message=success';
$url  = parse_url($data);
parse_str($url['query'], $url['query']);

//now, do something with parameters:
unset($url['query']['message']);
$url['query'] = http_build_query($url['query']);
$url  = http_build_url($url);
```

-please, note, that [`http_build_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) is a PECL function (`pecl_http` to be precise). The way above may look more complex, but it has benefits - first, as I've already mentioned, this will be easy to modify for working with complex parameters or multiple parameters. Second, it will produce valid url - i.e. encode such things as slashes, spaces, e t.c. - in result. Thus, result will always be correct url.

Comment: Great answer. I was first, but Your is more complete. +1 :).

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<?php
$str = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo $str = array_shift(explode('&',$str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer, but a disclaimer for future visitors:

1. I would strongly recommend the function: https://www.php.net/parse_url.
   And in that case:

   $current_link = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
   $arguments = explode('&', parse_url($current_link, PHP_URL_QUERY));
   print_r($arguments);
2. To build new url, use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php. This is the best, future modifications ready solution I think.

In that case this solution is a little overkill, but these functions are really great, and worth to introduce here.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$current_link_path = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 1);
$params = $_GET;
if ($params['message'] == 'success') {
    unset($params['message']);
}
$current_link_redirect = $current_link_path . '?' . http_build_query($params);
```